# Users entering the wrong decimal separators for US$ amounts

Tags: user-behavior, labels, formatting, currency, money

I have an application that accepts a dollar amount in $USD. Unfortunately, some people are foreign/visitors to the US and type in amounts with commas instead of periods: they format the number as XXX.XXX,00 instead of the US format of XXX,XXX.00. The different expected formats are causing issues. Even though the text input field  is showing the "$" as a field prefix and I have a placeholder of "USD", people are still typing the wrong format.

Example:

```
Expected US: 345.60
User Enters: 345,6
accounting.js translates to: 3456.00
```

The user then pays $3456.00! This is obviously not good and a huge mistake. At this point, I'm thinking it's very bad for me to even try to modify the text entered. Instead, I should force the user to type in the format correctly (exact). I can easily add a format/error message below the text field which describes the correct format in more detail with examples.

If I force them to type the correct format:

- Should I allow commas?
- Should I remove commas automatically from input?
- Should I throw an error when a comma is used?
- Should I throw an error when a decimal is not used?

Note: I'm forced into the USD $ format only at this time. Decimals are 99% common, but not required for the transaction to take place. I'm looking at using a regular expression to give the warning, such as `/^\d*(\.\d{2}$)?$/`.

Comment: Ref jQuery Masking: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Implementation-specific, so not an answer: Some platforms have widgets that ensure a standardized number representation is send to the backend, e.g. `<input type=number>` in HTML5.

Comment: http://youtu.be/0j74jcxSunY

Comment: How about you just disallow any and all comma's in the text field? There's no need for a comma, even if the user is paying over one thousand.

Comment: You show a marker of `$` or USD... so what? I'm still from Italy and I'm going to still use the same decimal marker as I'd use if it was asking for €. If I'm writing a document I'm not going to switch decimal marker for numbers of USD vs numbers in euro. I'd just consistently use `.` or consistently use `,`.

Comment: Is there a reason why your textbox can't accept both $13,45 and $13.45? I'm from a comma country, and every single suggestion here so far sounds like awful UX.

Comment: There is no connection between the $ sign and USD placeholder and the use of point vs comma

Comment: My bank's ATM just enters numbers from right to left, without commas. To enter $1,234.56, you just enter `123456` and the numbers slide from right to left starting at 2 decimal points. Just ignore commas and periods.

Comment: You know the locale of the user, it is in the HTTP header. You know the default formatting for this locale, therefore you could handle each user based on his locale. Not sure whether this corresponds with the users expectation :-)

Comment: you seem to have a pretty strong opinion about which format is *correct* and which is *wrong*. But it is all a matter of cultural point of view. I would recommend your input field to accept only one decimal separator, based on the user's locale, if you can access that information

Comment: @Fabian: You know the locale that's in the HTTP header. Don't assume it's correct / matches the user's preference.

Comment: @MSalters really? Do you know, when this is (not) the case? I know that when you want to define a locale for a user, you should use multiple ways, but not, that this can be plain wrong.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt This discussion on W3's site gives a nice background: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales

Comment: This is always a hard topic. I was surprised even paypal didnt really have a good solution...

Comment: Note that on some operating systems/software/locale combinations, the dot on the numeric keypad may switch to comma if that's relevant for that locale.

Comment: On the other hand, users with a locale that uses a comma as a decimal separator will not all use commas. Especially those coming from an IT background, so you cannot necessarily rely on a strict adherence to the user's locale.

Comment: Is it common at all in your application to input a higher precision than 1 USD, i.e. is it always `###,00` or `###.00`?

Comment: Does anyone ever input a thousand separator at all? I'm thinking `/[,.]\d{0,2}$/` for the cents... everything before that expression for whole dollars. I'd "properly" format the input number next to the field dynamically as feedback

Comment: @aross Yes, people do enter thousand separators and e.g. in South Asia you’ll find different grouping (lookup _lakh_). The separator can be any kind of space, apostrophe, comma or dot. The colon (and perhaps semicolon, dunno) and all kinds of hyphen are only common with non-decimal subdivisions as in times and dates or old, non-metric units of measurement. Unit symbols may be used in place of the decimal marker, e.g. 123€45. Imagine having to support all this for automatic recognition of hand-written values instead of an interactive digital form.

Comment: @Crissov yeah I know about various groupings, and all kinds of stuff people can put in their input (whether it's valid in any given locale or even invalid). The point I was trying to make is that I expect the bulk of the users only to enter a separator for cents, it's more work to input thousand separators and it doesn't make the input less ambiguous. My bank had the hard requirement to use comma as decimal separator for a while, whereas the numpad obviously only has a dot. It sucked

Comment: Can't you just make an warning icon and some text saying 'Make sure you are typing in US format whiling typing the numbers' that pops up whenever the user enters a comma?

Comment: @aross The grouping is there for a reason, it makes big numbers better to grasp. While one could anticipate that by automatically showing the input grouped, there’s still copy’n’paste and people looking at the keyboard instead of the screen. And @ Hyden, that’s the worst suggestion of all, UX-wise and i18n-wise.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's talk for a minute about user expectations and magic.

A user comes to your tool with certain expectations, and not every user's expectations are the same. You're seeing this first-hand. Culture, up-bringing and life experience all shape how a user will interact with a tool, opening a vast array of expectations to potentially meet.

One expectation almost every user has, however, is that when an illusionist or magician does a trick -- say, picking a card from a card deck -- the illusionist is always going to guess their card correctly.

Put another way, **if your tool is going to automate something, and going to guess what the user meant to type, it needs to get that guess correct**, or the user will end up disappointed or frustrated.

As you stated as well, they may end up overcharged which, if your system changed what they entered without their express desire and increased the amount, could make you legally responsible for the overcharge and get you in trouble.

To guess or not to guess; that is the question. So, we have two courses of action to choose from:

*Option 1: Analyze what's typed in and fix it*

In this case, you may need to look for a solution that can better accommodate all of the edge cases you're seeing. If accounting.js isn't correctly reformatting the text, you may need to do something more custom.

Enter the regular expression.

What you'll need to do is figure out all of the patterns you might encounter, which are correct, and which need to be changed. When we start looking at common cases,

```
 - ###.###,## > ###,###.##?
 - ###,###,## > ###,###.##?
 - ######,## > ###,###.## or ##,###,###?
```

It starts getting tricky pretty quick. To do this you'll need to do enough testing to know if your test and replacement patterns are getting it all right, and you'll need to watch out that new patterns don't emerge.

As well, if one of your patterns incorrectly changes the content, the user might not notice you've updated the amount (or, when you ask them to confirm the updated value is what they meant, they could miss an important change) and end up paying the wrong amount. What's more, if you did it for them, you might be legally on the hook.

*Option 2: Guide them to the right formatting*

This option will take a little less work and be safer from a number of standpoints. It's probably also more likely to end up in a pleasant user experience.

Here, still look for a strangely formatted string. Too many periods, too many digits between commas, a comma delimiting the final two strings of numbers, things like this.

What'd I'd suggest is using some implementation of live field validation to confirm that they're formatting their input correctly. When they type something strange, click out of the box, or try and submit the form, make sure to process the string to flag any of the tests you're looking for. If it fails a test, display a message next to or below the field (have a look at [some of these images](https://www.google.com/search?q=form%20field%20validation%20flags) for ideas of how to display the messages) that explains specifically what looks strange.

Don't change anything automatically -- ask them to do that themselves.

Check again as soon as you can whether they've made correct changes. Ideally do this before they have to hit the submit button again, when they focus-off from the field for example. If it's all good, display a message (in a friendly success color like green or blue) that tells them they successfully fixed the error. If they need to try and fix it again, re-display an error message, and indicate that you checked and they still have more to do.

```
Oops, looks like it's still not quite right. <error mitigation message follows.>
```

This way, they know they still have work to do and the form is explicitly asking for follow-up action.

*Edit: In conclusion...*

Consider the use cases in front of you and which option (or mix of the two) you feel you can implement to make the experience predictable and understandable for the user.

An interesting option that combines the two is the masking that @jjwdesign brought up in the comments. The form could either guide the user from the beginning how do do the conventions, displaying a subtle `___,___.__` in the field, or it might add/convert the punctuation as the user types a value in. We just need to be careful not to do this in a confusing way; as some point out throughout the comments on the page here, overriding a user's inputs can be disorienting.

Good luck!

Comment: I've decided on Option 2. I've got the warnings in place already with nice markup. What are you thoughts on using "masking"? Such as http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: _Guide them to the right formatting_, that's the right mindset, although you might want to _Force_ them into the right formatting, Splitting the input field into two parts, [integers].[decimals].

Comment: @Lars I think you're head's in the right place. But splitting the two up ends up building to the edge case instead of supporting the major case, in which most everyone will put the number in correctly.

Comment: @jjwdesign masking is certainly a neat option and helps show them what they should be doing, while also requiring specific input. Trouble can be if they add too large a number for the mask, but that's an implementation detail you can plan for.

Comment: This is all very well until you get some Indian users, who write numbers as, e.g., $1,00,00,000.34 (ten million dollars and thirty-four cents).

Comment: I do hope you understand `###,###,##` is not common at all. In the EU we use `###.###,##`.

Comment: @Dorus _EU_ is not at all unified in this. In France, they easily write `123.456$78` for a hundred dollars something.

Comment: @Dorus I'm in EU, too, yet we mostly use `### ###,##`.

Comment: @ROAL True, i use `###.###,##`, `### ###,##` and `######,##` myself. @yo' Dont you mean hundred thousand dollars?

Comment: Overriding a users input could also become a legal matter.

Comment: Any proposal that forces the user to a format that is not correct for their locale is not the right thing to do. As has been stated a few times, currency does not define numeric format -- locale does. Imagine being from the US and being forced to enter a dollar amount 199,99 This is not a matter of user's entering things the wrong way nor is it edge cases. This is a matter of the application not correctly handing valid inputs.

Answer (score 53):

Another option would be for the text field to ignore all non-numeric characters, and display appropriate formatting automatically.

For example:

```
User enters '3' -> Text field displays '0.03'
User enters '4' -> Text field displays '0.34'
User enters ',' -> Text field displays '0.34' (no change)
User enters '5' -> Text field displays '3.45'
User enters '6' -> Text field displays '34.56'
```

Comment: Interesting thought. Thank you. I might be able to do that with a mask with 'reverse' turned on.

Comment: This is a common thing to accountants and cashiers (it's on many cashdesks and even CC terminals), but it's very counter-intuitive to other people.

Comment: PayPal does exactly this, and it's incredibly weird the first few million times you use it.

Comment: @yo' no it's not. many online payment systems, even for food delivery, use this method.

Comment: Everyone will do it wrong the first one or two times, but in the end everyone will get it right. It's not a fast but very safe solution, PayPal's priority was obviously the latter, but the OP wants quick and simple input.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Not only incredibly weird, but annoying too

Comment: Every ATM I've ever used does this as well, excepting the cents. So it shouldn't be too unfamiliar to most people.

Comment: I run into this input mechanism on a regular basis and it took some time to get used to but i like it now. All my tax forms use it, the ATM, paypal. If you need to be 100% clear on what the amount is, this is the way to go.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Every ATM _in the US_ (emphasis mine).

Comment: @MichaelHampton And that distinction almost cost me. I'm from the US and used to ATMs behaving that way; Because of that, I recently went to an ATM the UK and typed in £6000 when I meant to extract £60.00. Fortunately I caught it before I hit submit (and hopefully my bank or the ATM would have limited that withdrawal as too high) but that was a bit scary.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: Maybe it's just in Germany, but here, food delivery services are neither "payment systems", nor do they require _you_ as the customer to enter a number and choose a custom amount to pay.

Comment: Forms like these tend to have problems with selecting text and copy/paste so make sure to get these things right to avoid frustration.

Comment: Why would an ATM allow you to withdraw cents? Do you actually have ATMs that spits out coins?

Comment: This is the most reliable method. Anything that tries to interpret based on known formats is bound to fail due to missing a format oddity or a new format coming into use. To address @borgardpd's use case, perhaps use this technique, but if the user does not enter a decimal point, do a popup or something asking for the 2 possibilities (i.e. for an entry of "104" in USD, that shows as "$1.04", verify by asking "$1.04 or $104.00"). Remember that we all see what we expect to see so this kind of error is fairly common.

Answer (score 28):

*Show* the user what's expected visually and *show* how the machine interprets the user's input.

My contribution to the brainstorm would be:

- Use a reference to the cheque-form of the old days :)
- Let the computer ignore all comma's and periods that the user enters (for that matter:  non-numerical characters)
- Show (if you're able to) an image in the background of your
  text-field, indicating the positions of the dollars, the cents and
  a period separating them.
- Use a mono-spaced font for the number
- Have the number right-aligned.

Now, as the user enters the amount, she'll see how the system interprets her input, automatically, with no script working (except maybe the script that rejects any comma's and dots):

[image: draft explainging the idea]

-

Comment: This. All of this.

Comment: I woudn't mind if the "3" starts in the leftmost _dollar_ position, and the cents position stays zeroed until you hit `.` or `,`. So the displays would be "3.00, 31.00, 314.00" until you hit `.`. As a final nicety, you could visually switch the hightlighted parts when you hit `.` or `,`. Don't forget that you will need a backspace when somebody adds a `.` or `,` intending to use it as a digit group marker.

Comment: This is great. Perhaps adding a 'cents' label would clarify it a bit further.

Comment: You'll end up with many users wanting to enter "$30" and ending up with $0.30. I would instead recommend showing "$       0.00" / "$       0.03", "$       0.31", "$       3.14", and so on. And instead of having a very small, nearly invisible decimal separator, make it use a full digit with. That will indeed require some scripting, but is less error-prone IMHO.

Comment: @MSalters Your suggestion tells us that the requirement of only one textfield can be by-passed by clever UX-design. +1

Comment: @nicodemus13 Yes, you're right, auch… That's why my circles always end up square :D But seriously, it is indeed 3.14159—2—65

Comment: @MSalters the trouble with switching to cents at a punctuation point is that some folks might type the in-between-dollars punctuation as well. When they type $314,159.65, we'd get "$314.15965" instead.

Comment: @Matt: True, that's why there should be a visual confirmation, and possible even a beep once you enter 314.159 < no fractional cents allowed.

Comment: If we're beeping (speakers off, deaf) or drawing the user's attention away from the text field we're reducing usability :-/. And it may not be apparent why the indicator was set off to the user. Better to keep the magic to a minimum, as it were.

Comment: @Matt I Love the phrase "keep the magic to a minimum".

Comment: Unless the decimal separator switches to a comma based on the user's locale, this is not a great solution. You should not be forcing users to specify a period for a decimal separator. Locale determines numeric format; not currency.

Answer (score 25):

You can do whatever you wish basically, as long as you provide a way to verify the input. I would personally dynamically display --next to the input field-- the amount at least partially written out, like

> ```
> [ 123.45     ] (123 US dollars, 45 cents)
> [ 123,45     ] (123 US dollars, 45 cents)
> [ 123,456.78 ] (123 456 US dollars, 78 cents)
> [ 123,456    ] (123 456 US dollars, 0 cents)
> ```

(`[]` contains the input, `()` contains the verification. Note the usage of a non-ambiguous space as a thousands seperator.)

I don't say the method of interpreting the input I propose is the best one, but you provide an instant verification. To me (coming from a country with a decimal comma rather than decimal dot), it's intuitive to treat `,XX` as cents, but to other people, `,XXX` means units. Since an instant verification is provided, no harm should be caused.

Note: Just remember to submit both the user input (for later check what they actually wrote in case of doubt) and the verification (to be sure what the user saw and believed is thhe interpretation), and re-check that they are consistent when the form is submitted.

Comment: A very good solution. I think the feedback that the program has interpreted my input correctly is very important in this case.

Comment: That is what I thought of too. This provides instant verification without magical guessing invisible to the user. Even better if there's a placeholder with example value: `e.g. 123,456.78`, so that the user instantly knows the formatting rules.

Answer (score 13):

You could create two fields - 1 for dollars and 1 for cents. In this way you don't need any formatting logic and you can strip out any non-alphanumeric characters when you save to a database.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's posted in only one field.

Comment: That's even worse: remember that users don't read what they should, and easily enter 123.45 in the first field and nothing in the second one. With your method, it's 12 thousand something, whereas they meant 1 hundred something.

Comment: @jjwdesign: What does “it’s posted in only one field” mean?

Comment: To solve the problem yo' pointed out, I’d suggest showing an error on any non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 7):

[*Locale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) is what this question is about. The fact that your users have to handle US dollars, does not mean they will do so in the locale of the 'owner' of this particular currency unit (USA). Date formats are another example of how different locales can render a value in ways that are ambiguous without knowledge of the locale the value was rendered in.

How a human expects to handle locale information depends on many factors which you cannot always predict as a programmer. What you **can** do, is give them enough information for them to know which locale they are experiencing the software in, or which aspects of that locale they have to deal with. In HTML, one way is to render localized [placeholders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) that show the expected input format.

You have expressed your concern about people accidentally processing incorrect amounts of money. It may be good to request the user for final confirmation before processing the request. If you analyze the entered amount and it's in an unusual format, because it uses decimal and grouping separators that are different from those in `en_US`, you can always show a message that asks the user if they entered the correct amount.

Comment: I would mark this as a correct answer. Your app should parse user input based on USER's locale and not assume anything. Same thing will happen (and wreak even more havoc) if your app requests a date! Just think how most of the world uses intuitive formats such as dd.mm.yyyy or yyyy.mm.dd, while your app would probably except "twisted" us mm.dd.yyyy...

Comment: I second user100858's comments. This is the correct answer. Any "solution" that forces the user to specify a period as the decimal separator if their locale uses something else (e.g. a comma), is not correct.

Answer (score 6):

The UX solution is to make it error free for the users no matter what format they're used to. Nothing more. Nothing Less.

I would recommend that you look into regex type solution:

> 1. make certain there are two digits after the comma (add a 0 if necessary)
> 2. then strip out all non-digits
> 3. then add the decimal point.

```
345,6 becomes 
345,60 becomes 
34560 becomes
345.60
```

Regardless of the process, or your back-end tools, make it easy for your users. If they expect to put in 345,6 (instead of 345.60) then let them.

Comment: From my recent perspective, changing the text entered into the field is a very bad idea. Even if it's to correct the format. It could result into payment  the incorrect amount.

Comment: Yes it might. Putting error notices is a very good alternative. Using two text boxes works but I would try to avoid that. Regardless confirmation screens are important

Comment: What do you think about jQuery .mask() plugin?

Comment: @jjwdesign:  I just experimented with the plugin. It should work in that one way or another it will force the user to put it into a format but I wasn't all that pleased with the results when I was trying to "break" it.

Comment: 34560 should not become 345.60 without some strong clues as to why. For example, you could always show the '.' and fill in the digits as the user types.

Comment: @hhamilton   You're correct. Any changes would have to explained as well as a confirmation that the number is correct.

Answer (score 5):

The banking site I use in Belgium only allows you to input the decimal notation but not the thousands separator.

It accepts either a **single** comma or a **single** dot for the decimal notation, but nothing else can be input.

I've done some more testing of how they treat the input field.

1. You can only use `,` or a `.` once for the decimal notation, no thousands separator
2. If you type `4,` then try to type `4,,` nothing happens, same as `4,000.` you can't add the `.`
3. You can type `4000.00` or `4000,00` and it converts both to `4000,00`
4. Copying and pasting isn't allowed
5. `4,000` gets converted to `4,00` - this is an issue, certainly for a banking site, but it would only occur for people that type in thousand separators, not as with the case of the OP where people are using commas for decimal notation. As copying and pasting isn't allowed it would only be for people that want to type the thousand separator, which is typically only done for readability, but you might need to test how many people would do that.

Comment: I did something like that, but it caused a huge mistake.

Comment: "so at the worst they will under pay" can actually be very serious, depending on what the payment is for and whether the user notices it.

Comment: I do agree that's an issue, the biggest problem I could see would be someone thinking they've paid for something when they haven't actually. However it's certainly less of an issue with someone paying `$3,456` instead of `$345.60`.

Answer (score 3):

In general try to avoid errors, they're the UI of last resort in my opinion. If there's anything that can be handled by system logic to avoid errors that should be the go to solution. Also avoid forcing them into a particular formatting. Try to anticipate the formatting they'll use, the microinteractions, and design your system around that.

A question for you...How often are people going to be entering decimal amounts into this field?

My suggestion would be to default format the number so it displays as  by default, when the user first sees it, and any user entry goes between the dollar sign and the decimal point? If you implement it that way any user entry is interpreted as the dollar amount, and if users won't ever enter decimal amounts you can stop there.

However, if you need to account for decimal amounts, you could prevent any alteration of the decimal amount until the user types "." on their keyboard, at which point they enter the decimal section of the field.
To solve your specific problem, you could treat "," the same way. When users key "," on their keyboard enter them into the decimal amount section.

So the user interaction would follow as such...

1. Enter dollar amount
2. Key "." or ","
3. Enter decimal amount
4. Finish

Comment: I'm forced into the USD $ format only. I also am forced into using only one field. Decimals are 99% common, but not required for the transaction to take place. I'm looking at using a regular expression to give the warning, such as: /^\d*(\.\d{2}$)?$/

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with an app for German users in the past. I sticked to the dot notation (for computers) and wrote a js to transform all commas to dots (no need to type the 1000s delimiter, the js would display whitespaces for that). I wanted to make sure that no comma reaches the backend server.

There were different respones by the users. Some did not note anything (e.g. non-Germans). Some were surprised, but adapted to it (e.g. bloomberg users). Some were confused and asked about the comma (e.g. heavy excel-only users).

Warning: this is just what I did. I am not an UX person who can jugde if such an approach is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use autoNumeric for number input fields, always I set it to accept both comma and dot/period/whatever you call it as decimal separator, without any thousands separator (seriously, who whould even use it in **input**?)
Unfortunately even if you set it up to accept comma as decimal separator when you paste number using comma it just drops it (I'm currently writing issue)... But at least on keyboard input it behaves properly

Answer (score 0):

Require the input to have a single dot followed by exactly two digits, with no commas. But allow the user to type multiple dots and commas into the field. If these requirements are not met when the user clicks outside the box, reject the input and show a text error so the user must manually remove stray commas and put a dot and the number of cents.

A note can be placed before the field: "Input must end in .XX, such as $XXXX.XX".

If the user types any commas but is forced to manually remove them, there is no possibility that the user assumes a comma was accepted. And since the dot and cent amount is required, the user is forced to see that the input includes cents.